Best way to make a soft body object return to its original shape after a collision
I have an object with a soft body that collides with a plane with a collider, and I want the object to return to its original shape after the collision. What's the best way to achieve this? I've been searching a lot for a solution but haven't found one yet.
Thanks in advance!

Try to tweak the Plasticity, if it doesn't work, please share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/
